# Can't push a json object into array using javascript and mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a problem pushing into my Student model data and its schema looks as below:

```
var StudentSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
        //validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your first name']
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
        //validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your last name']
    },
    worksnap: {
        user: {
            type: Object
        },
        timeEntries : [],
    },
    timeEntries : []
});
```

While my javascript code for pushing items looks like this:

```
Student.findOne({
            'worksnap.user.user_id': item.user_id[0]
        })
        .populate('user')
        .exec(function (err, student) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            //student.timeEntries.push(item); // this works
            student.worksnap.timeEntries.push(item); // this does not work
            student.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    //return res.status(400).send({
                    //    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                    //});
                } else {
                    console.log('item inserted...');
                }
            });

        });
```

As you can see, if I use timeEntries array outside the worksnap object it works fine, it inserts the item as object into that array... I just don't know why it is not working the same being inside worksnap object.

Is there any other option that I can add json objects into an array type in mongo

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)

> *Documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain JavaScript objects, not `MongooseDocuments`. They have no save method, getters/setters or other Mongoose magic applied.*

```js
Student.findOne({
    'worksnap.user.user_id': item.user_id[0]
  })
  .populate('user')
  .lean()//-----Added!
  .exec(function(err, student) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    //student.timeEntries.push(item); // this works
    student.worksnap.timeEntries.push(item); // this does not work
    student.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        //return res.status(400).send({
        //    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        //});
      } else {
        console.log('item inserted...');
      }
    });

  });
```

Comment: still not working after added lean(), it complains in the student.save() line